# MP3 to MP4 for javascript Mediasource

Tags: javascript, mp3, mp4, media-source, mux

Is it possible to convert MP3 to MSE-compatible fragmented MP4 within client side?

I tried **`mux.js`** with different MP3 files, but always return empty data.

so if it possible, how to do that? i currently have MP3 arraybuffer

Comment: Yes, it is possible! Just package the mp3 into the mp4 in JavaScript.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: The question only asked if it is possible. If you meant to ask a different question, please update your post to ask it.

Comment: Thanks @szatmary, i edited the question